# meaning of the word "grounding" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Some think your family allows you to stay connected to the person you once were, and if you are not that person anymore, that connection can be grounding, and valuable.

I looked up the word "grounding" in loads of dictionaries, but still have no idea what it means in the sentence.

Comment: Please provide the source from which this is quoted.

Comment: That is from a philosophy crash course

Answer (score 1):

grounding here means to be psychologically well.

The expression is to be grounded. However, in that sentence it is a little confusing. Connecting to family is grounding. Usually used in the passive but here it is used actively:

To ground someone=to give a person a sense of well-being

Swimming grounds me. I feel grounded when I swim. Swimming is grounding for me.

All those mean: Swimming gives me a sense of well-being.

The image is connection to the ground, as opposed to: being up in the air.

Answer (score 1):

The term usually takes the form "grounded". It refers to the metaphorical senses of "ground": connected, solid, fixed, based in reality, purposeful, sense of meaning. It contrasts with out-of-touch, in a bubble, isolated, flighty, fanciful, unmoored, wandering.

Answer (score 1):

**grounded** in psychological and emotional contexts refers to a stable, rational state-of-mind.

> When evaluating a person who will be working as a caretaker for 
>   young children, you should carefully assess whether they are psychologically grounded.

That which helps produce, or is conducive to, such a grounded state of mind can be called **grounding**, just as that which produces a state of alarm can be called **alarming**.